# Partial Function Application in Concatenative Programming Languages

Tags: haskell, concatenative-language

Say I have a haskell function `f n l = filter (n<) l` where it takes an integer `n` and list `l` and returns all of the integers in `l` greater then `n`.

I'm trying to figure out how to best write this function in a language like Joy. I've generally had good luck with converting the haskell function to pointfree form `f = filter . (<)` and then trying to rewrite it in Joy from there. But I can't figure out how to simulate partial function application in a concatenative language.

So far, I've tried to do something like `swap [[>] dip] filter`, but it seems like there must be a better/cleaner way to write this.

Also, I'm experimenting with writing my own concatenative language and was wondering if lazy-evaluation could be compatible with concatenative languages.

Comment: Your last sentence seems like a completely different question to me. Consider removing it, and asking it as a separate question.

Comment: @amalloy I included the question about lazy-evaluation in this post because the two concepts are somewhat related. Usually a function's parameters aren't evaluated until the function needs to return a value, so I was wondering if that could affect how I have to represent partially applied function in my experimental language. -Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`swap [[>] dip] filter` won’t work because it assumes `n` is accessible for each call to the quotation by which you’re filtering; that implies `filter` can’t leave any intermediate values on the stack while it’s operating, and `>` doesn’t consume `n`. You need to capture the value of `n` in that quotation.

First “eta”-reduce the list parameter:

```
l n f = l [ n > ] filter
n f = [ n > ] filter
```

Then capture `n` by explicitly quoting it and composing it with `>`:

```
n f = n quote [ > ] compose filter
```

(Assuming `quote : a -> (-> a)` a.k.a. `unit`, takes a value and wraps it in a quotation and `compose : (A -> B) (B -> C) -> (A -> C)` a.k.a. `cat`, concatenates two quotations.)

Then just “eta”-reduce `n`:

```
f = quote [ > ] compose filter
```

I put “eta” in scare quotes because it’s a little more general than in lambda calculus, working for any number of values on the stack, not just one.

You can of course factor out partial application into its own definition, e.g. the `papply` combinator in Cat, which is already defined as `swons` (`swap cons`) in Joy, but can also be defined like so:

```
DEFINE

  papply (* x [F] -- [x F] *)
    == [unit] dip concat ;

  f (* xs n -- xs[>=n] *)
    == [>] papply filter .
```

In Kitten this could be written in a few different ways, according to preference:

```
// Point-free
function \> compose filter

// Local variable and postfix
-> n; { n (>) } filter

// Local variable and operator section
-> n; \(n <) filter
```

Any evaluation strategy compatible with functional programming is also compatible with concatenative programming—[popr](https://github.com/HackerFoo/poprc) is a lazy concatenative language.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your [article](http://evincarofautumn.blogspot.com/2012/02/why-concatenative-programming-matters.html) is one of the main reasons I'm interested in concatenative programming!